# A question about convergence test in $2^n$ form

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For a decreasing and non-negative sequence {$a_n$}, we have:

if $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k \cdot a_{2^k}$ converges, then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ also converges.

Is the converse of this statement also write? That is:

If $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ converges, does $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k \cdot a_{2^k}$ also converge? And why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know the proof of if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k \cdot a_{2^k}$ converges, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ also converges? Because presumably, you could try to apply much of the same techniques. And either you succeed and that's good, or you fail and that's a big hint on where to start looking for a counterexample.

Answer (score -1):

$2a_2>a_2+a_3$

Simularly $4a_4>a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7$

$8a_8>a_8+a_9+a_{10}.......a_{15}$

Hence S= $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k \cdot a_{2^k} > a_2+a_3 +a_3.......$ ,  we know S and $a_1$ are finite hence proved.

---

$2a_2=2a_2$

$2a_3+2a_4>4a_4$

$2a_5+2a_6+2a_7+2a_8>8a_8$

Therefore 
$(2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k ) - 2a_1 > 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k \cdot a_{2^k} $

So the converse is also true.

Comment: The converse is **true**. Please check your counterexample again.

Comment: Oh yeah i guess you r right